# Rails - PreFill form using previous value store in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, simple-form, autofill

I have created a form,

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @resource], builder: ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder do |f| %>
<%= f.semantic_errors %>
<%= f.inputs do %>
<%= f.input :resource_template, :as => :select, :collection => Resource.select {|r| r.resource_template ==true }, :input_html => { :style => 'width: 20%;'} %> //added now ,just to try out how it may work.
<%= link_to 'COPY', admin_root_path, class: 'myButton' %> //added now,just to try out how it may work.
<%= f.input :title %>
<%= f.input :url %>

<%= f.actions %>
```

This form helps us creating new resources, now I have added a drop-down to select old existing resources.
How can i pre-fill the rest of form after clicking `COPY` of whatever value selected in the dropdown list?
***User might edit some prefill value and create its own new resource accordingly.***

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're OK with submitting the form immediately after the user selects an option, which id probably a bad idea, you're going to have to do this with JavaScript.

The exact implementation depends largely on how your app is configured, but the general approach would probably be something like:

1. Add an endpoint in your resources controller that accepts an `POST` request with an `:id` param and returns a `JSON` version of your resource
2. Add a change listener on your select box that sends a `POST` request to the endpoint in step 1. You'll also have to send the resource `id` as a param.
3. If the response from the endpoint in step 1 returns any data, use the keys and values in the `JSON` data to fill the form fields accordingly

This is a fairly broad question, so it's hard to give you a more detailed answer without knowing which JavaScript frameworks you have in your app, but this should point you in the right direction.

Comment: hi, I am doing same now but unable to upload an image using ajax
`<%= f.input :image, as: :file, label: "Image*" %>`
i have something like this in form.

Comment: You'll likely have to get the image URL and include it in your JSON response. Downloading the file and re-attaching it wouldn't make much sense if the image is already uploaded.

Comment: I believe Ajax doesn't support file upload. Any thoughts about it? Please share.

Comment: If you're copying data from an existing record the file should have already been uploaded. All you need to do is copy the URL where the file is located

Comment: yes. by that something like this appear ` Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.`

Comment: Yeah, you'll probably have to assign that value to a hidden field and have your controller use that param if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

On clicking of copy button you need to fire an ajax request with option selected in the select box, get data in controller with which you want to fill the form, in success callback of your ajax request , fill the fields returned from the ajax request.